# How to retrieve page id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I do an fql query like this.

```
SELECT page_id from page_admin WHERE uid=me()
```

I get page ids as float type. Something like `1.********E+14`. I am using php. How can I get it as an integer.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the id as an integer, since the id's of facebook are sometimes larger than 11 digits (E+14). **Try to parse the id as a string**.